# way to compare between index of two lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist

```
list1=['name1','name2','name3']
list2=[123,1234,12345]
```

I wanna say in python, if index of 'name1' in the first list is equal to index of 123 in the second list without knowing them.

For example 'name1' and 123 is user input.

I have tried many things like using .index, but I get an error.

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

and tried many other things but none worked as i wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
list1 = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
list2 = [123, 1234, 12345]

name = input("name: ")
num = int(input("num: "))  # don't forget to convert to int

if (name, num) in zip(list1, list2):
    print("Yay")
else:
    print("Aww")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are the same length

```
for count, data in enumerate(list1):
    if(list1[count] == list2[count]):
        print("yay")
```

If you just want to know if both lists contain the same data

```
for count, data in enumerate(list1):
    if(data in list2):
        print("yay")
```